# Porto - include Mageplaza LayeredNavigation in js file

Tags: magento2, frontend, custom, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

I'm making a custom theme based on porto. 
I'd like to include the `Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation/js/view/layer` in the `toolbar.js` file of the the Magento_Catalog module, in my custom theme.

I tried several ways to include the file, but each time, it breaks the `mage.productListToolbarForm` as events in the `_create()` function are not initialized anymore. But I have no error, which is something I don't understand.

Here is the require-config.js file of the mageplaza module :

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        mpLayer: 'Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation/js/view/layer'
    },
    shim: {
        mpLayer: ['touchPunch']
    }
};
```

Path to the file defined as mpLayer is `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation/web/js/view/layer.js`

Here is the definition of my toolbar, located in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/web/js/product/list/toolbar.js` :

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation/js/view/layer'
], function ($, ui, mpLayer) {
        _create: function () {
            this._bind($(this.options.modeControl), this.options.mode, this.options.modeDefault);
        },
        ...
}
```

Whenever I include the layer file of Mageplaza, events in the `create` function are not initialized. 
But I don't have any error.

With this code in my toolbar, events are initialized fine :

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui'
], function ($, ui) {
        _create: function () {
            this._bind($(this.options.modeControl), this.options.mode, this.options.modeDefault);
        },
        ...
}
```

Can somebody tell me if I'm doing something wrong ? I can't see my error and I don't get why events are breaking without errors.

Thank you!

Comment: What's the name of your js file ? Is it layer or mpLayer?

Comment: Hello BartZalas, I edited my question with the file locations. mpLayer is not the file name, the file name/path is app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation/web/js/view/layer.js

Answer (score 1):

You need extend widget:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation/js/view/layer'
], function ($, ui, mpLayer) {
   $.widget( "mageplaza.layerednavigation", {
   },
   _create: function () {

   }
```

or

```
$.widget('mage.productListToolbarForm', $.mage.productListToolbarForm, {
    ...
}
```

Please read also this:

https://extait.com/blog/development-tips-magento-2-ajax-layered-navigation/